# switch case going straight to end case

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i run this code, it runs through the entire switch to the end case, even when one of the prior cases is matched. I know this code is ugly, but it was working before i added one more case and now it doesnt work.

```
    function setColours() {
        var operatorName = document.getElementById("operator-header").innerHTML; 
        console.log(operatorName);

        switch(operatorName) {
                case "Great Western Railway":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "darkgreen";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                case "c2c":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "purple";
                case "Arriva Trains Wales":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,190,206)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                case "Chiltern Railways":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(45,106,140)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.borderTop = "1px solid #53c2f0"
                case "CrossCountry":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(136,0,56)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                case "East Midlands Trains":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(17,114,195)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(246,198,42)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #cc1e05";
                case "Great Western Railway":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "darkgreen";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #ffffff";
                case "Grand Central":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "black";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #fe8238";
                case "Greater Anglia":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(204, 204, 204)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(204,33,29)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #ffffff";
                case "Heathrow Express":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(109,56,122)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #d4d4d4";
                case "West Midlands Trains":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(90,30,79)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(240,140,38)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #ffffff";
                case "London Overground":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(240,140,38)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #1172c3";
                case "Merseyrail":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(250,203,51)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #ffffff";
```

when this is run, the console outputs the correct operator, but it still defaults to the end case

Comment: insert `break;` at end of each case

Answer (score 0):

Add 'break;' at the end of that case.

ex :

```
switch(operatorName) {
    case "Great Western Railway": doA(); break;
    case "c2c": doB(); break;
    case "Arriva Trains Wales": doC(); break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a break before every new case line such as

```
     switch(operatorName) {
                case "Great Western Railway":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "darkgreen";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
break;
                case "c2c":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "purple";
break;
```

The break is used to end the case block and start a new one, it separates them (the case blocks ) so the computer can identify each one separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need add `break` for each case, also should have `default` case if no one selected.

In your code the last case will be applied.

```js
function setColours() {
        var operatorName = document.getElementById("operator-header").innerHTML; 
        console.log(operatorName);

        switch(operatorName) {
                case "Great Western Railway":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "darkgreen";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                    break;
                case "c2c":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "purple";
                    break;
                case "Arriva Trains Wales":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,190,206)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                    break;
                case "Chiltern Railways":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(45,106,140)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.borderTop = "1px solid #53c2f0"
                      break;
                case "CrossCountry":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(136,0,56)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                      break;
                case "East Midlands Trains":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(17,114,195)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(246,198,42)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #cc1e05";
                case "Great Western Railway":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "darkgreen";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #ffffff";
                case "Grand Central":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "black";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #fe8238";
                case "Greater Anglia":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(204, 204, 204)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(204,33,29)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #ffffff";
                case "Heathrow Express":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(109,56,122)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #d4d4d4";
                case "West Midlands Trains":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(90,30,79)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(240,140,38)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #ffffff";
                case "London Overground":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "rgb(240,140,38)";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #1172c3";
                case "Merseyrail":
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(250,203,51)";
                    document.getElementById("section2").style.color = "white";
                    document.getElementById("horizontal-line").style.border = "1px solid #ffffff";
                      break;
                 default:
                    //if no case select
```